# Windows 7 laptop fonts DPI is too big breaking certain applications

Tags: windows-7, windows, display-settings, dpi

I have just installed windows 7 on a laptop and the fonts seem to be doing weird things, Ive adjusted the DPI back to 100% (was 125% by default) however certain applications (old delphi programmed ones) do not look correct still.

Here is a screen shot comparing my laptop to my PC running the same software (ROCLink RTU configuration software), the PC looks fine but the laptop does not.

Does anyone know where the problem may lie or what I should try next?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Perhaps figure out what font on XP it's using and make sure your Windows 7 install has it as  well.  It may be defaulting to a 'similar' font, with slightly different dimensions.

Comment: Both screen shots are windows 7 with 100% dpi and tahoma 8pt for all fonts.

Comment: Is this a new laptop with a high-dpi display?

Comment: Few years old but it may have some weird driver installed, it is just a normal 1680x1050 res screen.

Answer (score 0):

it might be, that the old Delphi-App uses the system default DPI (not user-defined).

The system DPI is not affected by the Control Panel setting.

The system default DPI however is set under following registry path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\Current\Software\Fonts\
```

The Key is named `LogPixels` and the decimal value should be 96. This corresponds to the 100% scaling setting in the control panel.

After a reboot, you are good to go.

Comment: We fixed it with a fresh install of windows, but I believe some other peoples laptops are affected so will try this on theirs and report back.